# git-version-gen why do I always get UNKNOWN-dirty?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm trying to generate git commit hash (or version) in my project, using a configure script that has the following:

```
AC_INIT([proj],
        m4_esyscmd([build-aux/git-version-gen .tarball-version]),
        [bug@example])
```

And Makefile.am I have the following:

```
BUILT_SOURCES = $(top_srcdir)/.version
$(top_srcdir)/.version:
    echo $(VERSION) > $@-t && mv $@-t $@

dist-hook:
    echo $(VERSION) > $(distdir)/.tarball-version
```

I have a line that debugs VERSION every time the configure script is ran:

```
echo $PACKAGE $VERSION
```

(As in described in the [git-version-gen script](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/astaff/project/opssrc/cups/autoconf-2.65/build-aux/git-version-gen)) But for some reason whenever I re-generate the configure script and run it, it gives me the following output:

```
proj UNKNOWN-dirty
```

What am I missing?

I also tried adding the build-aux folder including the script in git but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does `git tag` display anything?

if not you might try and tag something with `git tag -a vX.X`
and try running git-version-gen again

Comment: Nope, it doesn't.  Tried with `git tag -a ...` as well, nothing.

Comment: so what is the output of `git describe` after you add tag using `git tag -a ...`

Comment: i believe git-version-gen expects version tags to be in format `vX.X` so you might try creating one like this

Comment: Thanks!  that worked, however, i got a simple question, is there any way to set the version as the commit hash (sha1)?

Comment: when you checking something after tagging your version string will become something like this `vX.X-x-aaaaaaaa` where vX.X is the original tag, x is number of commits since tag was applied and aaaaaaaaa is short sha1 of commit on HEAD